# d3.zoom unexpected behavior: what am I missing?

Tags: d3.js

I've got a behavior with d3.zoom whose solution I'm sure is to be found in something I'm obviously missing, but I can't seem to make sense of it.  I've reviewed and reviewed examples, and seem to be following them precisely, but something is causing this particular function to not behave.

The following, rather than zoom to focusElement as intended, flips between zooming away from it, and then back to it.  The values of -focusBBox['x'], for example, flip between the following two values on subsequent executions.  2500 is svgWidth/2

-208.586669921875

2500

```
    function focusObject(focusElement) {
       var focus = document.getElementById(focusElement);
       var focusBBox = focus.getBoundingClientRect();

       gridGroup.transition().duration(750).call(zoom.transform,d3.zoomIdentity.translate(-svgWidth / 2, -svgHeight / 2).translate(-focusBBox['x'], -focusBBox['y']));
    }
```

Can someone just please take a moment to give a kind virtual slap to point out what it is that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha! From a previous incarnation of this particular endeavor, I was using a fixed-position SVG to capture mouse events and applying my transformations to a child SVG. The fact that getBbox() returns local coordinates and getBoundingClientRect() returns coordinates from the outer SVG coord system thus mucked things up.

I've included the revised snippet below.  Note that focusBBox2 uses getBBox rather than getBoundingClientRect(), and that grid is the parent SVG as distinct from gridGroup in the original post.

```
function focusObject(focusElement) {
    var focus = document.getElementById(focusElement);
    var focusBBox2 = focus.getBBox();
    grid.transition()
     .duration(750)
     .call(zoom.transform,d3.zoomIdentity.translate(focusBBox2.x, focusBBox2.y));
}
```